# View HTML files from Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed on my primary computer and Windows 10 1909 installed on secondary computer. I usually build websites. If I want to view a simple HTML file, I just open it on the browser. But what if I want to view those on my secondary PC.

What should I do to open those HTML files on my secondary computer on a browser?

Comment: Use `ssh` to access your Ubuntu. The best way I find is to use `ssh` in VScode editor that has integrated functionality and it works very well. Or else you can use any remote desktop application to access primary PC like Anydesk or Teamviewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to do it by using file sharing in Ubuntu.

In nautilus (file explorer on ubuntu), right click on the specific folder/file and select properties, and then go to local sharing, and select the required boxes you want.

Now go to windows and press `windows + r` and type `\\<IP Address of Ubuntu PC>` i.e., two back slashes followed by the  and press enter. And there you can see all the shared files in the file explorer

If you want to see the files for local host server from ubuntu to linux

Open Windows and type `http://<IP Address>:<Port>` in the address bar of any browser. And you are connected to the local host from Ubuntu on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to manage files on multiple devices is to use some sort of version control or use a usb and plug it into whatever computer you wish to see the file.

Comment: this can also be done but remote login using `ssh` seems more easy and feasible.